# Adding secondary file association in Windows?

Tags: windows, file-association

In Windows, you can right-click a file, and there is an option which lets you choose which program to launch with this file. So, for example, when user right-clicks a .cdr file, he can choose `Open With -> Corel Draw` option, and it would be launched with Corel Draw.

Now, I need to add certain program to that list (program has to be launched with some other parameters, as well). But I do not want to change the default program for that file. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following registry keys control this list:

1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Explorer \ FileExts \ *.FileExtension* \ OpenWithList
2. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ *.FileExtension* \ OpenWithList

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166549%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information on the format.

Comment: Thanks! And is there some way to set those keys from .bat file?

Comment: Check out the REG command: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: But how should I do it if I don't want to erase old value, just add something to it?

Comment: Add another key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext\OpenWithList` using the format on the linked article. Make sure you add your application to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` also, as explained in the article.

Comment: You can figure this out for yourself pretty easily :) http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4465/68245003.png